SAP Workzone and XSUAA: Scopes Empty
roles created via Kyma
xsuaa.yaml
kind: ServiceInstance
metadata:
  name: services-xsuaa
  namespace: <namespace>
spec:
  serviceOfferingName: xsuaa
  servicePlanName: application
  parameters:
    xsappname: services-xsuaa
    tenant-mode: dedicated   
    description: Security profile of screen control
    scopes:
      - name: $XSAPPNAME.User
        description: Read Only
      
      - name: $XSAPPNAME.Manager
        description: Read and Edit
      
      - name: $XSAPPNAME.SuperUser
        description: Read, Edit and Delete

      - name: uaa.user
        description: UAA  

      - name: $XSAPPNAME.<app>-xsuaa-scope
        granted-apps: 
          - $XSAPPNAME(application,<app>-xsuaa)

    role-templates:
      - name: User
        description: User (read only)
        scope-references: 
          - $XSAPPNAME.User

      - name: Manager
        description: Manager
        scope-references: 
          - $XSAPPNAME.User
          - $XSAPPNAME.Manager

      - name: SuperUser
        description: Super User
        scope-references: 
          - $XSAPPNAME.SuperUser
          - $XSAPPNAME.User
          - $XSAPPNAME.Manager
       
      - name: TokenExchange
        description: UAA
        scope-references: 
          - uaa.user

      - name: access-<app>-api-v2
        description: Access to <app> api v2
        scope-references:
          - $XSAPPNAME.<app>-xsuaa-scope

    role-collections:
      - name: <app>-SERVICES-SUPERUSER
        role-template-references:
          - $XSAPPNAME.SuperUser
          - $XSAPPNAME.User
          - $XSAPPNAME.Manager
          - $XSAPPNAME.TokenExchange
          - $XSAPPNAME.access-<app>-api-v2

      - name: <app>-SERVICES-MANAGER
        role-template-references:          
          - $XSAPPNAME.User
          - $XSAPPNAME.Manager
          - $XSAPPNAME.TokenExchange
          - $XSAPPNAME.access-<app>-api-v2

      - name: <app>-SERVICES-USER
        role-template-references:          
          - $XSAPPNAME.User
          - $XSAPPNAME.TokenExchange
          - $XSAPPNAME.access-<app>-api-v2

    oauth2-configuration: 
      redirect-uris:
        - https://**.hana.ondemand.com/**
        - https://**.applicationstudio.cloud.sap/**
        - http://localhost:5000/login/callback  

    

---
apiVersion: services.cloud.sap.com/v1
kind: ServiceBinding
metadata:
  name: services-xsuaa
  namespace: <namespace>
spec:
  serviceInstanceName: services-xsuaa
  secretName: services-xsuaa
  externalName: services-xsuaa
  secretRootKey: services-xsuaa-service-key

roles add in BTP

deployment.yaml appsapui5
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: html5appdeployer-<app.sapui5>-services
  labels:
    app: html5appdeployer-<app.sapui5>-services
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: html5appdeployer-<app.sapui5>-services
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: html5appdeployer-<app.sapui5>-services
    spec:
      containers:
        - image: <image>/<app.sapui5>-services-ui
          imagePullPolicy: Always
          name: html5appdeployer-<app.sapui5>-services
          volumeMounts:
            - name: html5-repo-app-host-volume
              mountPath: /etc/secrets/sapcp/html5-services-ui-apps-repo/html5-services-ui-app-host-instance
              readOnly: true
            - name: services-xsuaa-volume
              mountPath: "/etc/secrets/sapcp/xsuaa/services-xsuaa"
              readOnly: true
            - name: destination-volume
              mountPath: /etc/secrets/sapcp/destination/html5-services-ui-destination-instance
              readOnly: true
          env:
            - name: SAP_CLOUD_SERVICE
              value: "<app.sapui5>.services.ui"

            - name: EXIT_PROCESS_AFTER_UPLOAD
              value: "true"
              
            - name: SUBACCOUNT_LEVEL_DESTINATION
              value: "true"            
            
      imagePullSecrets:
        - name: <secret-repo-docker>
      volumes:
        - name: html5-repo-app-host-volume
          secret:
            secretName: html5-services-ui-app-host-binding
        - name: services-xsuaa-volume
          secret:
            secretName: services-xsuaa
        - name: destination-volume
          secret:
            secretName: html5-services-ui-destination-binding
        
---
apiVersion: services.cloud.sap.com/v1
kind: ServiceInstance
metadata:
  name: html5-services-ui-app-host-instance
spec:
  serviceOfferingName: html5-apps-repo
  servicePlanName: app-host

---
apiVersion: services.cloud.sap.com/v1
kind: ServiceBinding
metadata:
  name: html5-services-ui-app-host-binding
spec:
  serviceInstanceName: html5-services-ui-app-host-instance

---
apiVersion: services.cloud.sap.com/v1
kind: ServiceInstance
metadata:
  name: html5-services-ui-destination-instance
spec:
  serviceOfferingName: destination
  servicePlanName: lite
  parameters:
    HTML5Runtime_enabled: true
    version: "1.0.0"

---
apiVersion: services.cloud.sap.com/v1
kind: ServiceBinding
metadata:
  name: html5-services-ui-destination-binding
spec:
  serviceInstanceName: html5-services-ui-destination-instance

call url sapui5 inside portal workzone
https://.launchpad.cfapps.br10.hana.ondemand.com/<app.sapui5>/user-api/currentUser
result: scopes empty
    "openid",
    "user_attributes",
    "uaa.user"
  ],

As the scope that was linked in btp to the user does not appear when the application is accessed, this generates a 401 error in the API.
If I generate the token manually and make a request to the api, I can get the data without any problems.
Locally, using default-env.json together with the sapui5 app I can also communicate with the API and obtain data.
